# How to keep NULL values in attributes until the user choses from the value map?

Tags: qgis, domains

When I set up a attribute domain by using value map in QGIS then create a feature which in turn pops up the attribute pop up window - the value mapping for the attribute inserts the first value from the mapping into the attribute by default.  I would like the value mapping to leave the attribute as null UNLESS an analyst chooses to click on the attribute in the attribute pop up window to reveal the value mapping pull down AND THEN choose a value for the attribute.   Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `NULL` as the first value to your map.
[image]

Comment: some of my domain lists are lengthy so I am using the "Load Data from Layer" which works well - If I want to use the suggestion above I would need a 'Insert' row at the screen above - is there any way to get around hand-typing all my domains if I need a Null as the first value?

Comment: It's probably the easiest to export to a CSV and edit that.  Or if you are working with the latest master version you will have this option in the GUI starting from now [df672e8](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/df672e88f15d10f663c7015f4b99596d43a7d794).

Comment: that's good news, albeit in the version I am using now I cannot get the CSV ingest to work properly